# Haven't been able to play DOOM on vulkan driver

Tags: doom-2016

I've a msi r9 380 4gb, which is capable of running Vulkan and all my drivers are up to date, *used driver booster for that*, but the game still won't launch.

I'm not using any capture software or fps counter which is said to be cause of this fault.

If here isn't the place to ask this kind of question I'd appreciate if you'd point me to the proper place.

I know how to change back to opengl on cfg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, by downloading latest amd control software at amd website and reinstalling it

Comment: *reinstalling it* - you mean the amd software, and not the game, right?

Comment: @camelCase Yes. I wanted to reinstall just the Vulkan driver, but I only found it bundled with the amd software.